# MongoDB Greater than and not null?

Tags: mongodb

How can you query on a field that is greater than x, and not null?

Here's what I would expect to work, but it returns empty results:

```
db.articles.find({ field: { $ne: null, $gte: 0.5 } })
```

whereas this does return results:

```
db.articles.find({ field: { $ne: null } })
```

One obvious solution is to set up my application so null values are never entered for that field, but this seems weirdly inflexible.

Comment: Your logic is working fine. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XuBSn8k6Txz) Can you update this demo to show the issue happening.

Comment: Ah you're right, turns out the issue is completely unrelated. I had been saving values as strings, not realizing that the `toFixed()` function in Javascript returns a string. Previously didn't catch this since I was doing all my comparisons in JS which automatically converts strings to numbers when comparing. Thanks!

Comment: No probs. I have realized that half of the issues are resolved internally when we try to recreate the issue in a sandbox environment before posting the question. Hope it helps in future.

Comment: Good advice - didn't know about Mongo Playground either so that'll definitely be useful